# Specify Multipart File Upload with Swashbuckle .NET

Tags: .net, swagger, swashbuckle

I am trying to specify an `IOperationFiler` for Swashbuckle (Swagger) in .NET.

Compared to the code examples I have found, there seem to have been some breaking changes in the OpenApi classes.

The commented lines in the following code do not compile any longer with .NET 6 and Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 6.2.3.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer;
using System.Reflection.Metadata;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

namespace BK.DocumentService.Api.Swagger
{
    public class FileUploadOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {
            if (operation.OperationId == "xxx")
            {
                //operation.Consumes.Add("multipart/form-data");  <-- does not compile

                operation.Parameters
                    .Add(
                        new OpenApiParameter
                        {
                            Name = "file",
                            Required = true,
                            Style = ParameterStyle.Form,
                            //Type = "file", <-- does not compile
                        });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have been looking around in the OpenApi code repo but could not figure it out.
https://github.com/microsoft/OpenAPI.NET/tree/vnext/src/Microsoft.OpenApi

Does somebody know how to specify this the "new way"?

Ultimately, i would like to get a generated file upload box on my swagger page.

Thanks for any help on this, Mike

Comment: look at this [article](https://medium.com/@niteshsinghal85/testing-file-upload-with-swagger-in-asp-net-core-90269bc24fe8). it shows different ways to upload files using swagger.